# the meaning of "draw" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm watching this bull riding competition. This anchorman was saying that the contestant was bucked off the bull's back in 3 seconds, and he was very disappointed with himself. Then, he said the contestant had another chance with another bull, then he talked for a while about the bull and how strong it is. After that, the other guy said that this should be a good draw for him, now what do we mean by "a good draw for him" in this context? does that mean a draw for the contestant from disappointment? Or a good chance for the contestant to draw attention? Or does he mean the bull some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to the matchup with another bull that has been arranged for him:

***[Draw](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/draw)***:

Sports & Games

> - a. The arrangement of competitors in a tournament in which the matchups are made at random.
> - b. A matchup or opponent in such a tournament.

AHD